# ZF RenameUpload filter not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-filter

I'm trying to upload an image, very basic. Here's my input filter file:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Filter\StringTrim;
use Zend\Filter\StripTags;
use Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload;
use Zend\Validator\File\Size;
use Zend\Validator\File\MimeType;

class MyFilter extends InputFilter 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'image',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => [
                    [
                        /* 'name' => RenameUpload::class, */
                        'name' => 'filerenameupload',
                        'options' => [
                            'target' => './data/uploads/images/.ext',
                            'overwrite' => true,
                            'randomize' => true,
                            'use_upload_extension' => true,
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'validators' => [
                    [
                        'name'    => Size::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'max' => '10MB',
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => MimeType::class,
                        'options' => [
                            'mimeType' => [
                                'image/jpg',
                                'image/jpeg',
                                'image/png'
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
...
```

I checked `$request->getFiles()->toArray()` and the uploaded image is there. In the controller I do:

```
$postData = array_merge (
    $this->request->getPost()->toArray(),
    $this->request->getFiles()->toArray()
);

$form = new MyForm;
$form->setInputFilter(new MyFilter);
$form->setData($postData);

$form->isValid()                      // this returns true.
```

When I check the uploads folder, nothing is there. It's not a filesystem issue since the folder owner is the same as the user running apache; and the permissions are 755.

I also noticed if I delete the folder where it's suppose to write to, `$form->isValid()` still returns `true`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the proper upload directory if you want to use the **RenameUpload** filter. Like the following

```
'./data/upload/images/'
```

Use **array_merge_recursive()** instead of **array_merge()**. Because **array_merge()** orverrides similar array keys (just keeps the last one).

And this will upload the the image to the target assigned by the **RenameUpload** filter.

```
<?php

...

if($form->isValid()) {
    // Move uploaded file to the assigned directory.
    $data = $form->getData();

    // Do other stuff
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the "moving" get's done after `getData()` is called, rather than `isValid()`.

Comment: Yes! You are right! I have said about **array_merge_recursive()** because it keeps all the values if any **key** is similar to those arrays you are merging.